# Identifying Physics Equipment

Tags: education, instrument

We are clearing out some old cupboards at school in our science department and have come across three different sets of physics equipment with no labels or instructions. Please could people kindly identify these if possible and what they would be used for in terms of a practical and if it is therefore worth keeping them?

Just want to mention that the picture of the wooden piece of equipment laid down on the table has 3 metal cups in it as this isn't clear from the picture.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's hard to tell with so little context, and these might not be complete sets of equipment, only parts. Do you have any more information about them?

Comment: Trying to reverse-engineer someone else's disassembled hacks is an exercise in pain, I fear.